# How to webscrape multiple items in <tr> bracket and split them in 3 variables with python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website with multiple  brackets. My plan is to have 3 variables (oem, model, leadtime) to generate the desired output. However, I cannot figure out how to scrape this webpage in 3 variables. Given I am new to python and BeautifulSoup, I highly appreciate your feedback.

Desired output with 3 varibales and the command:
print(oem, model, leadtime)

```
Renault, Mégane E-Tech, 12 Monate
Nissan, Ariya, 6 Monate
...
Volvo, XC90, 10-12 Monate
```

Output as of now:

```
Renault Mégane E-Tech12 Monate
Nissan Ariya6 Monate
Peugeot e-2086-7 Monate
KIA Sportage5-6 Monate6-7 Monate (Hybrid)
Jeep Compass3-5 Monate3-5 Monate (Hybrid)
VW Taigo3-6 Monate
...
XC9010-12 Monate
```

Code as of now:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#Inputs/URLs to scrape: 
URL = ('https://www.carwow.de/neuwagen-lieferzeiten#gref')
(response := requests.get(URL)).raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
overview = soup.find()

for card in overview.find_all('tbody'):
    for model2 in card.find_all('tr'):
        model = model2.text.replace('Angebote vergleichen', '')
        #oem?-->this needs to be defined
        #leadtime?--> this needs to defined
        print(model)
```

Comment: Isn't this your account as well, from where you used to ask similar questions? https://stackoverflow.com/users/14913446/jaa

Comment: nope this is another issue. would appreciate your help here

Comment: Oh yes, that's you - the same poster. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The brand name is inside `h3` tag. You can get the parent with this approach `.find_all("div", {"class": "expandable-content-container"})`

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


#Inputs/URLs to scrape: 
URL = ('https://www.carwow.de/neuwagen-lieferzeiten#gref')
(response := requests.get(URL)).raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
overview = soup.find()

for el in overview.find_all("div", {"class": "expandable-content-container"}):
    header = el.find("h3").text.strip()
    if not header.startswith("Top 10") and not header.endswith("?"):
        for row in el.find_all("tr")[1:]:
            model_monate = ", ".join(
                list(map(lambda x: x.text, row.find_all("td")[:-1]))
            )
            print(f"{el.find('h3').text.strip()}, {model_monate}")
        print("----")
```

Comment: thanks a lot! any chance to get in the end 3 variables and not 2 (with join)? objective is to do print(X, Y, Z) and not print(X, Y)

Comment: Z == `'Angebote vergleichen '` ?

Answer (score 0):

the parts of the car model info that you're trying to scrape are actually stored in separate `td` tags, meaning, you can just access their index to get corresponding info, try the code below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.carwow.de/neuwagen-lieferzeiten#gref").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

for tbody in soup.select('tbody'):
    for tr in tbody:
        brand = tr.select('td > a')[0].get('href').split('/')[3].capitalize()
        model = tr.select('td > a')[0].get('href').split('/')[4].capitalize()
        monate = tr.select('td')[1].getText(strip=True)
        print(f'{brand}, {model}, {monate}')
```

Comment: the monate includes the str('Angebote vergleichen') which is not correct. Also model includes the information that needs to be stored in var monate

Comment: @Irra updated the code!

Comment: now I get a error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop...carwow_lead times_v2.py", line 9, in <module>
    brand = tr.select('td > a')[0].get('href').split('/')[3].capitalize()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 965, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'select'